# How to express the Black Derman & Toy Model in a $dr=A\,dt+B\, dW$ form?

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, bdt

The Black Derman & Toy ([BDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Derman%E2%80%93Toy_model)) model is given by

$$d(\ln\,r)=\left(\theta(t)-\frac {d(\ln\sigma(t))}{dt}\ln r\right)\,dt+\sigma(t) \, dW.$$

How can one rewrite the BDT model as $dr=A\,dt+B\, dW$, using Ito??

I searched everywhere but no answer.

Comment: Aren't we going to compute Ito Lemma for f(x) = exp(x)

Comment: No, because $\exp(x)' = \exp(x)$.

Comment: Can we close this question? It seems to be entirely obvious/basic knowledge.

Comment: @Drew I think this question is way more brainy than some others out there ...@Student T seeing Gordon's answer your comment is the solution if we let $A$ depend on $r_t$ and $\sigma_t$ ...

Comment: @Drew: I think this question is not too bad.

Answer (score 3):

If we are going to have the form 
\begin{align*}
dr = A dt + BdW_t,
\end{align*}
Then both A and B are functions of $t$ and $r_t$, otherwise, $r_t$ is normal. However, note that 
\begin{align*}
r_t = \exp\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma(t)}\bigg(\int_0^t \theta(s)\sigma(s) ds +\sigma(0)\ln r_0 + \int_0^t\sigma^2(s) dW_s\bigg)\Bigg).
\end{align*}
That is, $r_t$ is log-normal, assuming that both $\theta(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ are determinsitic.

From 
\begin{align*}
d(\ln\,r_t)=\Big(\theta(t)-\frac {d(\ln\sigma(t))}{dt}\ln r_t\Big)\,dt+\sigma(t) \, dW_t,
\end{align*}
we obtain that
\begin{align*}
dr_t &= d\big(e^{\ln r_t}\big)\\
&= r_t\Big( d \ln r_t + \frac{1}{2}\langle d\ln r_t, \, d\ln r_t\rangle\Big)\\
&= r_t \bigg[\Big(\theta(t)-\frac {d(\ln\sigma(t))}{dt}\ln r_t + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(t)\Big)\,dt+\sigma(t) \, dW_t \bigg].
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you explain a bit how you derive the solution for $r_t$ .. with the exponential (2nd formula). I don't see that this is the solution that easily ..

Comment: Hi Richard, you can assume that $r_t = r_0 \exp(a(t)+\sigma(t)W_t) $ and then work out $a(t)$.

Comment: I missed the term $\big(\sigma(t)-\sigma(0)\big)\ln r_0$ in the exponent of the $r_t$ formula, which I am now added.

Comment: My original $r_t$ formula does have some errors, and I have now corrected. The conclusion still holds.

Comment: Changed $\langle dr_t, \, d r_t\rangle$ to $\langle d\ln r_t, \, d\ln r_t\rangle$.

Comment: but $\frac{d}{dx} exp(f(x)) = f'(x) * exp(f(x)) $ in our case where $f(x) = ln(x)$ we have  $\frac{1}{x} exp( ln(x))$ which is $1$ and the second derivative is $0$ thus you get $dr_t = dr_t$ which is true but does not bring us anywhere.

Comment: @Richard: Here, I treat $X_t=\ln r_t$ as a process, and I used Ito's formula of the form $df(X_t) = f'(X_t) dX_t + \frac{1}{2}f''(X_t)\langle dX_t, \, dX_t \rangle$.

Comment: Oh - yes, then it looks correct to me. Clever trick to connect $r_t$ and $\ln r_t$ ... I already +1'd you ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I have a "+" sign for the second term (not negative)

dr =r[(θ(t)+ d(lnσ)/dt * lnr + 1/2*σ^2)*dt + σ*dW]

I left out the subscript t's.....

You can let V = log r then Apply Ito and solve for A and B... where B = r*σ

Comment: if you use latex, it will be more readable.

Comment: I would appreciate that too